# extract list of combinations and their count values from a matrix dataframe?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following matrix:

```
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'TFD' : ['AA', 'SL', 'BB', 'D0', 'Dk', 'FF'],
                    'Snack' : ['1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '0'],
                    'Trans' : ['1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1'],
                    'Dop' : ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1']}).set_index('TFD')
df_test = df_test.astype(int)
matrix = df_test.T.dot(df_test)
print matrix
=>>>
           Dop  Snack  Trans
    Dop      4      2      3
    Snack    2      3      2
    Trans    3      2      4
```

​What I would want to yield:

```
Dop-Snack      2     
Snack-Trans    2      
Trans-Dop      3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no special requirements regarding the order of the pairs:

```
import itertools
for c, r in itertools.combinations(matrix.columns, 2):
    print("{}-{}\t{}".format(c, r, matrix.loc[c, r]))

# Dop-Snack     2
# Dop-Trans     3
# Snack-Trans   2
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations

Comment: you mistyped the k with r, but I got it, thanks very much bro :D

Comment: True, shouldn't edit in-place too much. You are welcome ;)